# Highcharts' navigator and dependency arrow (ganttChart)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, dependencies, gantt-chart

While tinkering with Gantt charts, I noticed that using `navigator` and `dependency` arrows sometimes behaves weirdly depending on the current zoom.

On this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16kyxuvh/3/) (hopefully, for you too), when fully de-zoomed, the dependency arrow splits and sometimes disappears (though it seems to happen intended because it happens when the `start` date of the task gets out of the "view"). [image: weird behavior: split dependency arrow]

This doesn't seem to be happening when removing the `min` and `max`attributes of `yAxis` in the chart configuration, in this demo, but [doesn't seem to always fix it](https://jsfiddle.net/16kyxuvh/4/)

But, for instance, if [you add the `navigator` to the "Interactive Gantt" demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rbm1y2Ls/), the bug still happens.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea ? I don't think I saw an Issue about that on the git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was reported on Highcharts github and it is already resolved, see: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10804

As mentioned there it is expected to be included in the next maintenance version v7.1.3.